# Проблема создания новой виртуальной среды

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь выполнить задачу, в которой я должен запустить `poetry virtual environments` и выполнить некоторый код, который должен запустить свою виртуальную среду и выполнить в ней свой код.

Но есть проблема: виртуальная среда остается прежней.

```
import typer

def typer_main(path_to_bath: str = typer.Argument('test')):
    subprocess.run(path_to_bath)


def script_main():
    """Точка входа для запуска скрипта."""
    typer.run(typer_main)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_main()
```

run.bat (C:\User\Documents\prj2)

```
cd path/to/prj2
poetry install
poetry show -v
```

runner.py

```
import subprocess

import typer

def typer_main(path_to_bath: str = typer.Argument('test')):
    subprocess.run(path_to_bath)


def script_main():
    """Точка входа для запуска скрипта."""
    typer.run(typer_main)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_main()
```

start.bat

```
poetry install
poetry run python runner.py ./path/to/prj2/run.bat
poetry show -v
```

Запуск:

```
./start.bat
```

Вывод

```
(project1-py3.10) PS C:\Users\User\Documents\project1>./start.bat

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\Users\User\Documents\project1> poetry install

Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 0 installs, 17 updates, 0 removals


...


(project1-py3.10) PS C:\Users\User\Documents\project1>poetry show -v

Using virtualenv: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\project1-lbkdIgRk-py3.10

...

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\Users\User\Documents\project1>cd C:\User\Documents\prj2

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\User\Documents\prj2>poetry show -v

Using virtualenv: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\project1-lbkdIgRk-py3.10 

...


(project1-py3.10) PS C:\User\Documents\prj2> poetry install

Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 0 installs, 16 updates, 0 removals

...

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\User\Documents\prj2>poetry show -v

Using virtualenv: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\project1-lbkdIgRk-py3.10

...

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\User\Documents\prj2>
```

Почему виртуальная среда не была изменена на новую виртуальную среду?

Comment: Если виртуальная среда для проекта уже создана, новая для этого проекта не будет создана (потому что зачем?)

Comment: Какую проблему вы вообще так пытаетесь решить? Не понятно зачем еще одно виртуальное окружение.

Comment: Задача рассчитана на создание кучи новых процессов.

Comment: Как связано создание виртуального окружения и создание кучи новых процессов? Можно спокойно "кучу новых процессов" запускать в одном и том же виртуальном окружении.

Comment: Нет, нужно запускать эти процессы в отдельном окружении, читайте внимательно вопрос.

Comment: Там не написано зачем. Там как неоспоримый факт указано, что каждый процесс ДОЛЖЕН создавать свою виртуальную среду. На практике это не нужно делать. Если бы вы указали, какую-то проблему вы пытаетесь этим решить, тут было бы что обсуждать. А так я бы сказал, что вы делаете странное.

Comment: Теоретически (если вы пытаетесь сделать какое-то подобие контенеризации на коленке) вам больше подошел тут докер, а не это извращение с poetry.

Comment: Ахаха, здесь не поспоришь)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что subprocess позволяет запускать другие процессы только под своим окружением poetry под которым был запущен скрипт. Это можно решить добавив `deactivate` для деактивации уже имеющегося окружения в файл `run.bat` и `poetry shell` для активации нового окружения.

Также есть более элегантное решение, в котором используется модуль `os`

```py
import os

bat_file_path = r'C:\путь\к\вашему\файлу\ваш_файл.bat'

# Запуск .bat файла
exit_code = os.system(bat_file_path)

# Проверка результата выполнения
if exit_code == 0:
    print("Файл успешно выполнен")
else:
    print(f"Ошибка при выполнении файла. Код завершения: {exit_code}")
```

Здесь нет необходимости напрягаться по поводу активации и деактивации виртуального окружения, так как эта команда запустит отдельный процесс со своим окружением

Comment: Старайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Как буду свободен напишу комментарий с примерами